# Bitwise operations on big bit-vectors

Tags: objective-c, c, bitwise-operators

I would need to run bitwise operations (and, or, xor, shifts, sets, etc..) on arrays of bits. So far I have used the 128 bit type to do so, but now I have met the need to work with bigger arrays. After a bit of search I found that CFBitVector and vBigNum in the Accelerate Framework could store this big numbers, but it appears that they don't have the operations I want.

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Language used is Objective-C or C

Thanks for your support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regular arrays and interpret them as bit arrays. Let's say you use an array of chars, so every element has 8 bits. If you want to access bit 231, you will find it in 231/8=28th element of the array (the 231%8=7th bit of that array). This is easy when you deal with individual bits. If you use masks and shifts, it's not that easy but you can write some functions to do that.

Comment: So far what you suggest is the best solution I have found,
http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~cheung/Courses/255/Syllabus/1-C-intro/bit-array.html

The binary functions however need to be written as you stated.